# Web server connection to SQL Server: Response Packet [Malformed Packet]

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008

I am seeing very, very sluggish performance between my web server (which handles HTTP web services connections) and a separate server running Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I have been capturing packet traffic on the web server trying to understand why things are running so slowly. I am using Wireshark to capture the packet traffic.

The apparent problem is that the web server is sending TDS packets to the data server--each packet followed by a response from the data server with

Response Packet [Malformed Packet]

in the Info field. The packet sent from the web server appears to have an invalid checksum.

Has anyone seen this type of problem before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause for this is TCP chimneying.  Try disabling on both the client and the server (one at a time of course) and see if that addresses the issue

Answer (score 0):

TDS (tabular data stream) packets are SQL data, so the type of packet you're seeing is what I'd expect for SQL. The fact that the packets arrive at the SQL server malformed with an invalid checksum makes me think you've got a driver problem or a physical layer problem on the web server side of things. Start at the physical layer and work your way up. What's the speed and duplex settings on the NIC of the web server? Do they match the settings on the switch port that the web server is connected to? Have you swapped out the network cable on the web server? Does the switch port show drops, crc errors, etc.? Can you try a different NIC on the web server? After you've checked those, try updating the NIC driver on the web server.